# Security Implications from Base64 Image

Tags: malware, google, audit, injection, code-execution

I copy / pasted a data:image/png;Base64 image from a Google search into a Google Slide, before realizing it was a BASE64 image. Is there any possibility that this contains malicious code, or any way to check it?

> [...]data:image/png;base64,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

I did run it through a Base64 Validator and it produced the .png, but just concerned it may have done something else.

Comment: Base64 is just ASCII text. It's unlikely that copying it would do anything malicious.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing magic about base64. It's just a way of storing arbitrary binary data in a character set that is safe for printing and transmission as pure text (ASCII).

It's no more dangerous because it's base64 encoded. For it to be dangerous, it would have to use a vulnerability in some piece of code involved in rendering the image. That vulnerability will be the same - unless it's in the base64-decoding part.

TL;DR: If you worry about images, stop browsing the web. You have no control over what images you get. The encoding doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Data by themselves cannot cause any harm. *Their handling can*, though.

An [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image) is not an executable program (so as to infect or compromise your computer), it's just guidelines for your computer to represent a picture on the screen.

The [format of the image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_format) is just a way to store the image in a computer. Others can have better compression, others better quality etc. [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is not an image format per se, like [png](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) or [jpg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG), but it transforms binaries to text in order for them to be transmitted through the internet without problems.

As you can understand, just having an image (in any format) does not represent a problem by itself.

The program that will handle the image, though, *may be vulnerable to malformed data*. This, in turn, can lead to security issues (e.g. see [here](https://imagetragick.com/)). However, as you can understand, malformed images target specific programs; it's not like you'll malform an image and this will allow you to hack into all the computers that will open it (unless all the computers use the same vulnerable program to open it)

> Is there any possibility that this contains malicious code, [...]

In principle, yes, there is a possibility. Practically speaking, I don't think so.

> [...] or any way to check it?

There are discussions online on how to do it (e.g. [here](https://blog.reversinglabs.com/blog/malware-in-images) and [here](https://virusdie.com/blog/how-to-find-images-infected-with-malware/)). Usually scanning the image with an antivirus should work.